# How to pass value of a variable to a script within div in a Svelte component?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, svelte, svelte-component

I am implementing a Svelte component to show a [Freestar](https://help.freestar.com/help/freestar-standard-implementation) Ad. It requires to place a piece of HTML with the `script` tag in it, like in this example:

```
<div id="desktop_native">
  <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
    freestar.config.enabled_slots.push({ placementName: "some_placement_id", slotId: "some_slot_id" });
  </script>
</div>
```

The strings `some_placement_id` and `some_slot_id` are configured in the dashboard and so must be passed as variables for each instance of the component.

How do I pass those values to the HTML section from the Svelte `<script />` section that is in the same file?

Whatever I have tried just ends up in the HTML, i.e. it's not substituted for the value from the variable. Like in this example (below) where I tried to escape curly braces using one of the techniques [mentioned on this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2290fc67e7c0479881a266abb34e0f4d?version=3.20.1).

[image]

Comment: Did you try to create the script tag entirely declaratively from the Svelte script part?

Comment: That wouldn't work - that way it would be just some code executed with the rest of the JavaScript code. It must be executed at the specific location in the DOM because the snippet pulls an iframe with the actual ad and adds it to the wrapping div. The purpose of the component is to display an add on the page.

Comment: Yes I understand but I am suggesting not to execute the script itself, but to build the script tag itself, something like
`let myScript = document.createElement('script');
myScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
...

myDiv.append(myScript)
`